# Third-party cookie blocked?

Tags: node.js, express, cookies, jwt, ngrok

So, I am having a NodeJS backend with JWT login using cookies, and a Vue client, I used

```
res.cookie('token', token, {

maxAge: 1728000000,

secure: true,

});
```

to send the cookies to the client and save into the browser, I worked perfectly in localhost, but when I deploy the server to ngrok and client to Netlify, I get a warning "Third-party cookie will be blocked",

I did a little research and found out some articles saying that Chrome is going to restrict third-party cookies, I tried to send the token via res.send and save it manually in the client by cookies.set('token', response.data.token) but it did not work, can someone give me a solution ? Should I change to Session storage ?